# Looking for word or phrase that describes something that is beneficial, enjoyable, and pleasing?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase that describes several properties:

- Very beneficial
- Enjoyable (to do / to experience)
- Pleasing (to view)

Related is *panacea*. However, this is cure-all, which is good, but it doesn't imply enjoyable. Another related phrase is *apple of my eye*, which is what I cherish above all (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_of_my_eye)).

The context is a personal reflection and description where I outline some aspects of design that I think are important. The usage would be:

> Finally, typography is my ...

Answer (score -1):

If you’re talking about it being personally pleasing and enjoyable, you might try the French loan-phrase [*raison d’être*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raison_d%27%C3%AAtre), literally “reason for being” and pronounced /ˌɹeɪzɒ̃ ˈdɛtɹə/ in English, a phrase which colloquially tends to have a connotation of describing the one thing that truly draws purpose for you.

Comment: It is indeed personally pleasing and enjoyable! Even though I think it should be for everyone (one can hope...), personal is indeed enough for now. _Raison d'être_ is a very good suggestion, thank you! I feel like it might be a tad too dramatic in this context though.

Comment: @user3714447 informally you could say something is your "bag" or your "thing". Moving more formally, you could also consider it's your "passion".